# Rooted device, modified the hosts file and rebooted but still have access to blocked sites

Tags: root-access, hosts

I tried to block Facebook on Chrome by changing the hosts file but to no avail. What could possibly went wrong?

1. [Modifying hosts file does not have any effect](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108653/modifying-hosts-file-does-not-have-any-effect)

I followed exactly what the op did and rebooted, but I could still have access to Facebook.

[image: doesn't work] [image: I have root access]

Comment: Your hosts file is completely broken. There should be no space after any dot in a hostname. Remember: It's `facebook.com` not `facebook. com`. The latter one assigns only `facebook.` to another IP. Any errors in the `hosts` file is silently ignored and that's it.

Comment: I'm guessing whatever keyboard you are using assumes the periods to be line ends and adds the space for you during the construction of these lines. Investigate how to turn that off while composing this file.

Comment: @GiantTree If you look at the second screenshot, that appears to have spaces too, in a place you wouldn't expect any. I suspect it's an awful font rather than spaces actually in the file.

Comment: As a plus to what @GiantTree said, I'll point out that lines 3 and 4 do nothing.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman depends on the local network. If one host has the hostname `facebook` (that's possible) then it's blocked as well. It's just not needed because there won't be a host with that hostname.

Comment: @GiantTree Well, that's what I meant. The system tries to redirect the full URL to the IP on the left, so, technically, it couldn't understand a website name devoid of its domain.

Comment: Wow. Thank you all so much with such a quick response! There is no space between facebook.com Yes, it's just the font problem. Also, I was trying to add more lines like line 3 and 4to see whether it would work.

Comment: Whenever I type facebook.com on chrome, it would redirect me to m.facebook.com.

Comment: @GiantTree I just used another device ( Nexus 7 2013 4.4.4 rooted) to test: cleared chrome data. Add the line m.facebook.com (no space between.and com). Rebooted. Still doesn't work. Very frustrating... any help is much appreciated:)

Comment: Can you try with a different browser, possibly with no history of facebook being opened there?

Comment: @Firelord I just did. I cleared all data on the stock browser and dolphins browser. I rebooted and tried to access Facebook on them. I still can. But thanks for the suggestion though:)

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding these three hosts name and replace ip address 127.0.0.1

```
    facebook.com  
    www.facebook.com  
    m.facebook.com
    mobile.facebook.com
```

As I checked when typed facebook.com, the site will be redirected to m.facebook.com, so we won't be able to access.